# Using S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage-class-specifier

I read about the new storage class `S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval` and I want to use it when I upload files to S3 using the AWS CLI (command line interface). I read on https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html that the storage class options are:

```
--storage-class (string) The type of storage to use for the object. Valid choices are: STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY | STANDARD_IA | ONEZONE_IA | INTELLIGENT_TIERING | GLACIER | DEEP_ARCHIVE. Defaults to ‘STANDARD’
```

How do I use the `S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval` storage class with the CLI and do I need to install a specific version of AWS CLI?

Comment: Hi, I installed `aws-cli/2.4.6` and I can confirm it works there with `--storage-class GLACIER_IR` (cp or sync).

Answer (score 3):

AWS seems to have only made it available through the [S3 API-Level Commands](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/index.html) at this time with `aws s3api put-object`.

When using [put-object](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html), you have the choice of using the `--storage-class` of `GLACIER_IR`. Tested this the other day for a [blog post](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/s3-glacier-instant-retrieval-deep-dive-which-s3-storage-class-is-right-for-me), which worked a treat. Why they haven't included it in `s3` is a mystery to me.

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key folder/filename --body file --storage-class GLACIER_IR
```

This is the case as of `aws-cli/2.4.5`, but I can also see a [Pull Request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/6590) in the GitHub repo where someone has submitted a change to add it to `aws s3`, so this answer may change.

Answer (score 1):

[CHANGELOG](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/v2/CHANGELOG.rst) of aws-cli says updated in 2.4.4 version.

> 2.4.4
>
> api-change:s3: Introduce Amazon S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval storage
> class and a new setting in S3 Object Ownership to disable ACLs for
> bucket and the objects in it.

(Document does not seem to be updated yet, though.)

Comment: I installed `aws-cli/2.4.5` but still in its documentation (`aws s3 cp help`), I can't find an option for `S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval`. ```--storage-class  (string)  The  type  of storage to use for the object. Valid choices are: STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY | STANDARD_IA  |  ONE-ZONE_IA  |  INTELLIGENT_TIERING  |  GLACIER | DEEP_ARCHIVE. Defaults to       'STANDARD'```

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6587

Comment: Does `--storage-class GLACIER_IR` work? Written in aws-blog. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-glacier-is-the-best-place-to-archive-your-data-introducing-the-s3-glacier-instant-retrieval-storage-class/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: It's an invalid choice with `aws-cli/2.4.5`. There is a PR and it will probably be available soon.